# Trying to zip only an extension

Tags: zip, 7-zip, cbr

im looking for a solution, since I'm changing all my comics cbr to cbz I'm using 7zip, but i have a problem: sometimes some cbr have many layers of subfolders inside.
Im trying to find a way to just zips the jpg extension, even if have many folders inside, anyone know a way?
Thanks.

```
for /d %%X in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" ".\%%X\*"
```

Example:

```
comics/
  Comic1/
    morefolder/
      comic1file1.jpg
      comic1file2.gif
      comic1file3.png
  Comic2/
    morefolder/
       morefolder02/
         comic2file1.jpg
         comic2file2.gif
```

At the end i need in a zip

```
Comic1.zip
  comic1file1.jpg
  comic1file2.gif
  comic1file3.png

Comic2.zip
         comic2file1.jpg
         comic2file2.gif
```